# GCP HTTP Load Balancers With SSL Certificates for Multiple Websites

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to setup an HTTPS Load Balancer on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) for my Virtual Machine (VM) Instances.

The documentation shows that you can only have a maximum of 10 SSL Certificates per Load Balancer.

**How can I use an HTTPS Load Balancer on GCP with more than 10 domains?** I've got way more than 10 websites. All of these websites require an SSL connection. All HTTP connections will be redirected to HTTPS connections.

How can I provide an SSL connection to all of my websites using an HTTPS Load Balancer on GCP? I've got it figured out for non-secure connections but I need them to all be secure. What should I do here?

Do I create a separate unique SSL Certificate specifically for the Load Balancer, and then put the SSL Certificates for each website on the VM Instances?

Answer (score 1):

For your case study, you could use one network load balancer listening to ports 80 and 443 that would directly transfer request to the backend servers.
The requests would be directly transferred for example to your Apache virtual hosts configured with SSL certificates for each of your websites.

If you are using an HTTPS load balancer, you are limited to 10 SSL certificates, that is to say ten websites.

What you may try to do is to have an HTTPS load balancer for each 10 domains,with SSL certificates installed, and all the load balancers would point to a backend instance group where all your websites are configured and SSL certificates installed.